# No Product matches the given query - Search form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a search form in Django, but I'm receiving this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=cddsc
No Product matches the given query.
```

This is my form:

```
<form class="search_form" action="/search/" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q" Placeholder="Buscar">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Search">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> Buscar</span>
  </button>                 
</form>
```

This is my url:

```
url(r'^search/$', 'reviews.views.search'),
```

This is my view:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        message = 'You search for: %r' % request.GET['q']
        return render(request,'search.html', {'msg':message})
    else:
        message = 'You submited an empty form'
        return render(request,'home.html', {'msg':message})
```

The message returns that no product matches, but I didn't query the product model yet. Why Django returns this message?

This is my product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    #inserir campo imagem
    #inserir slugify na url do produto
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)

    def reviews(self):
        return Review.objects.filter(product = self.pk)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

Comment: Where is your db query which does not return a product?

Comment: Are you sure the same view is being called? Try changing the HTML to  `action="/search/"`.

Comment: [render shourt cut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) requires `request` as first parameter.

Comment: I didn't query the db yet. I changed for /search/ and didn't work and also implemented request on render. I updated my code, take a look

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
return render('search.html', {'msg':message})
```

to

```
return render(request, 'search.html', {'msg':message})
```

and

```
<form class="search_form" action="search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="" Placeholder="Buscar">
```

to

```
<form class="search_form" action="/search/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" Placeholder="Buscar">
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

I found the source of "No Product matches the given query." message. In urls.py

```
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product'),
```

was executed before

```
    url(r'^search/$', 'reviews.views.search'),
```

Please change urls.py

From

```
    url('^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    #produt
    #url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product'),
    #submit reviews
    url('^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/review_submit/$','reviews.views.single_product'),
    #search
    url(r'^search/$', 'reviews.views.search'),    
)
```

to

```
    url('^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    #search
    url(r'^search/$', 'reviews.views.search'),
    #produt
    #url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product'),
    #submit reviews
    url('^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/review_submit/$','reviews.views.single_product'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I implemented all changes and still doesn't work

Comment: The changes were implemented in the GitHub version and they work. What is your error message?

Comment: Still the same message

Comment: I looked at some other question from you and I cannot reproduce your error message. Is there a chance you have your code on GitHub ?

Comment: Thx. I found the source of "No Product matches the given query." message. In urls.py r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$' was executed before r'^search/$'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47382/discussion-between-fragles-and-filipe-ferminiano)